# Twitter - Could not authenticate with OAuth (401) Error

Tags: delphi, twitter, oauth

So, I'm doing a simple twitter app in Delphi and because I can't find a library already that works I decided to create my own. With the authenticate process I follow everything and get the Access token and secret token just fine.

When I try to use them (in the following code) I get the error {"error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth."}

This is true for both read and write requests (verify and posting). Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been bashing my head against the wall over this.

Commands in the code below are the contents of the variables directly above the comments.

**EDIT: Even just *knowing* what might cause "Could not authenticate with OAuth" instead of the more specific errors ("Invalid signature", "Missing parameters") would be of a giant help!**

**EDIT 2: Wireshark packet results.**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2011 20:11:13 GMT
Server: hi
Status: 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com"
X-Runtime: 0.01306
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 114
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=300
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=xxxxxxxxxxx; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Tue, 06 Sep 2011 20:16:13 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
{"error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth.","request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json?status=This%20is%20a%20test."}
```

Code:

```
function TTwitter.SendRequest(Method: String; URI: String; Params: Array of String): ISuperObject;
const
  AuthHeaderFormat = 'OAuth oauth_nonce="%s", oauth_signature_method="%s", oauth_timestamp="%s", oauth_consumer_key="%s", oauth_token="%s", oauth_signature="%s", oauth_version="%s"';
var
  oauth_nonce,
  oauth_timestamp,
  SignKey,
  BaseString,
  Signature,
  AuthHeader,
  ResponseStr : String;
  BaseStringParams : Array of String;
  JSON : ISuperObject;
  I, J : Integer;
  EmptyParams : TStringList;
begin
  oauth_nonce := GenerateNonce;
  oauth_timestamp := GenerateTimeStamp;
  SignKey := fConsumerSecret + '&' + fAccessToken;
  J := 0;
  SetLength(BaseStringParams, Length(Params) + 6);
  For I := Low(Params) To High(Params) Do
    begin
    BaseStringParams[J] := Params[I];
    Inc(J);
  end;
  BaseStringParams[J] := 'oauth_consumer_key=' + fConsumerKey;
  BaseStringParams[J + 1] := 'oauth_nonce=' + oauth_nonce;
  BaseStringParams[J + 2] := 'oauth_signature_method=' + oauth_signature_method;
  BaseStringParams[J + 3] := 'oauth_token=' + fOAuthToken;
  BaseStringParams[J + 4] := 'oauth_timestamp=' + oauth_timestamp;
  BaseStringParams[J + 5] :=  'oauth_version=' + oauth_version;
  BaseString := CreateBaseString('POST', URI, BaseStringParams);
  //POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D0F95A680F2231F689C702FCECAD1D449%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1314988258%26oauth_token%3DXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DThis%2520is%2520a%2520test.
  AuthHeader := Format(AuthHeaderFormat, [oauth_nonce,
                                          oauth_signature_method,
                                          oauth_timestamp,
                                          fConsumerkey,
                                          fOAuthToken,
                                          Signature,
                                          oauth_version]);
  //OAuth oauth_nonce="0F95A680F2231F689C702FCECAD1D449", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1314988258", oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_token="XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_version="1.0"
  fHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', AuthHeader);
  EmptyParams := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    If Length(Params) > 0 Then
      begin
      URI := URI + '?';
      For I := Low(Params) To High(Params) Do
        begin
        URI := URI + Params[I] + '&';
      end;
      URI := Copy(URI, 1, Length(URI) - 1);
      //http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?status=This%20is%20a%20test.
    end;
    If Method = 'POST' Then
      begin
      ResponseStr := fHTTP.Post(URI, EmptyParams);
    end
    Else If Method = 'GET' Then
      begin
      ResponseStr := fHTTP.Get(URI);
    end;
    JSON := SO(ResponseStr);
    Result := JSON;
  Except
    On E:EIdHTTPProtocolException Do
      begin
      MessageBox(0, PChar(E.ErrorMessage), '', 0);
      //{"error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth.","request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json?status=This%20is%20a%20test."}
    end;
  end;
  EmptyParams.Free;
end;
```

Comment: First of all, check date/time settings on your machine. Then, how do you generate Signature? I don't see this in your code. Are you sure that it's correct? Third - have you tried to parse headers of the response (or sniff them with Wireshark)? Probably there are details of error within them.

Comment: The date and time settings are correct, same with the signature (not withstanding what needs to be included in this particular signature). If either of these were incorrect the authentication steps which use the same things would have also failed. Furthermore there are specific errors for those problems. I have looked at the raw headers and the only error contained is the one I have listed. This is why I am so stumped.

Comment: It returns details. I've tried to authorize with invalid token. Here is what I got in response (in Java there is getErrorStream which returns any useful data even if server replied with non 200): {"error":"Invalid \/ expired Token","request":"\/1\/account\/verify_credentials.json"}. Try to get that data. The easiest way is to use Wireshark I think.

Comment: That's the thing, the json response error is 'Could not authenticate with OAuth." I just now ran Wireshark and there is no other error associated with it. Original post edited with wireshark results.

Comment: Ok. For some errors it really returns just "Could not authenticate with OAuth".

Comment: Try to remove some parameters (e.g. nonce). Try to run request with the same nonce. Try to generate invalid signature. Does it return the same response for all of these errors?

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question, but there is an excellent Delphi interface to Twitter here: http://www.simonjstuart.com/delphi-stuff/ttwitter/

Comment: @Nick: That was one of the first things I tried. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @Shcheklein Yes, the same basic response comes back for all errors. Nothing specific at all!

Comment: I don't know then. Try to run the same request with some other tool or library, sniff HTTP package and compare it with yours. For example, there is twurl (https://dev.twitter.com/console) by Twitter or a lot of libraries for Java, C#, Ruby, Python, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that on this line:

`fHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', AuthHeader);`

The way the component handles custom headers is that the delimiter for text is a comma. This means the program was adding a \r\n (new line) after every parameter I included for OAuth. No wonder it failed! Twitter wasn't even receiving the parameters!

Since I was checking the header before I added it to the headers I didn't even think that was the problem.

Thank you for your help! I probably wouldn't have delved into the code this deeply otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple library/class to send status updates (post messages):

http://code.google.com/p/delphi-twitter-library/