# Accessing Ubuntu One API results in "401 UNAUTHORIZED" or "400 BAD REQUEST"

Tags: delphi, oauth, indy10

I am using Delphi XE2 with Indy 10 to access the Ubuntu One API. So far so good. I was able to get the OAuth Token from the Cloud as [described](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/otherplatforms). Now I want to start using the API (like [described](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/index)):

```
function TUbuntuOneApi.DoRequest(const URL: String): String;
var
  RequestParams: TStringList;
  HeaderIndex: Integer;
const
  OAuthAuthorisationHeader = 'OAuth realm="", oauth_version="%s", oauth_nonce="%s", oauth_timestamp="%s", oauth_consumer_key="%s", oauth_token="%s", oauth_signature_method="%s", oauth_signature="%s"';

begin
  RequestParams := SignOAuthRequestParams(URL, fOAuthAppToken, fOAuthAccessToken);

{  OAuth realm="", oauth_version="1.0",
  oauth_nonce="$nonce", oauth_timestamp="$timestamp",
  oauth_consumer_key="$consumer_key", oauth_token="$token",
  oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
  oauth_signature="$consumer_secret%26$token_secret"
  }

  HeaderIndex := IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.IndexOfName('Authorization');
  if HeaderIndex >= 0 then
  begin
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Delete(HeaderIndex);
  end;

  // Solving: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323036/twitter-could-not-authenticate-with-oauth-401-error
  IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := false;

  IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', Format(OAuthAuthorisationHeader, [
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_version']),
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_nonce']),
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_timestamp']),
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_consumer_key']),
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_token']),
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_signature_method']),
      TIdURI.URLDecode(RequestParams.Values['oauth_signature'])
    ]));

  // Execute
  Result := IdHTTP.Get(URL);
  RequestParams.Free;
end;

function TUbuntuOneApi.Test: String;
begin
  //Result := DoRequest('https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1');
  Result := DoRequest('https://one.ubuntu.com/api/account/');
end;
```

Calling https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1 results in "401 UNAUTHORIZED". Calling https://one.ubuntu.com/api/account/ results in "400 BAD REQUEST". The OAuth Library is from [SourceForge](http://oauthdelphi.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oauthdelphi/) and works with Dropbox (Dropbox accepts the OAuth-Params if they are in the Query-String). The Tokens are correct and valid. What am I doing wrong?

BTW:

```
function SignOAuthRequestParams(const URL: String; OAuthAppToken, OAuthAccessToken: TOAuthToken): TStringList;
var
  Consumer: TOAuthConsumer;
  ARequest: TOAuthRequest;
  Response: String;
  HMAC: TOAuthSignatureMethod;
begin
  HMAC := TOAuthSignatureMethod_PLAINTEXT.Create;
  // Consumer erzeugen
  Consumer := TOAuthConsumer.Create(OAuthAppToken.Key, OAuthAppToken.Secret);

  // Request erzeugen
  ARequest := TOAuthRequest.Create(URL);
  ARequest := ARequest.FromConsumerAndToken(Consumer, OAuthAccessToken, URL);
  ARequest.Sign_Request(HMAC, Consumer, OAuthAccessToken);

  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.AddStrings(ARequest.Parameters);

  ARequest.Free;
  Consumer.Free;
  HMAC.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point, the newly created token can be used to authenticate to
>   other methods, on the Ubuntu SSO service, but can not yet be used with
>   the Ubuntu One API. We need to tell Ubuntu One to copy the newly
>   created token from the SSO service. This is done by issuing a `GET`
>   request to the following URL, signed with the new OAuth token.
>   From [Ubuntu One: Authorization page](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/otherplatforms).

Shame on me, I forgot to do that.